# ASP.net Control in FormView ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a DropDownList control in ItemTemplate of FormView_Product, how do I modify the code below to reference to my DropDownList1?

```
String strQty = DropDownList1.Items[DropDownList1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
```

Code

```
}
protected void btnBuy_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // test to remind customer to login first
    if ((string)Session["sFlag"] != "T")
    {
        Type csType = this.GetType();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorLogin);
    }
    else
    {
        // test to remind customer to login first
        if ((string)Session["sFlag"] != "T")
        {
            Type csType = this.GetType();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(csType, "Error", scriptErrorLogin);
        }
        else
        {
            OleDbConnection mDB = new OleDbConnection();
            mDB.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source="
            + Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/webBase.mdb");
            OleDbCommand cmd;
            //insert item purchased to itemsTable
            int intOrderNo = (int)Session["sOrderNo"];

            FormViewRow row0 = FormView_Product.Row;
            String strProductId = ((Label)row0.FindControl("lblProductId")).Text;
            Int32 unitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)row0.FindControl("lblUnitPrice")).Text);
            float floUnitPrice = float.Parse(strUnitPrice);
            String strQty = DropDownList1.Items[DropDownList1.SelectedIndex].ToString();
            int intQty = int.Parse(strQty);
            string strSQL = "INSERT INTO itemsTable(iOrderNo, iProductId, iQty, iUnitPrice)"
            + "VALUES (@OrderNo, @ProductId, @Qty, @UnitPrice)";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, mDB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNO", intOrderNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductId", strProductId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", intQty);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", floUnitPrice);
            mDB.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            mDB.Close();
            Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code for the page and the code behind

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 DropDownList DropDownList1 = (DropDownList)FormView_Product.FindControl("DropDownList1");
 String strQty = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```